# gRPC: creating Blocking or Future Stubs

Tags: java, future, grpc, stub, grpc-java

Lately, I 'm studying to build the gRPC client-server interaction.

I wrote a gRPC service :

```
service SearchService {

    rpc Find (SearchReq) returns (SearchRes);

}
```

and then I should invoke it on the client side using stub(another java-application).

whats the difference between this two types of stubs??

```
SearchServiceGrpc.SearchServiceFutureStub futureStub = SearchServiceGrpc.newFutureStub(channel);

SearchServiceGrpc.SearchServiceBlockingStub blockingStub = SearchServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
```

`blockingStub.find(request);` - for blocking

`futureStub.find(request).get();` - for future

I understand how works Futures in java,
but I don't understand what happens inside gRPC and what type of stubs invocation is more productive

I find no information on google about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The various stubs are implemented using the same async API (ClientCall). Your choice doesn't matter for the grpc internals.

But the APIs have the normal expected limitations. For example: if you use blocking, that thread cannot be used until the RPC completes.

Comment: it turns out that a future and blocking stub does not differ in performance except for a call in the client? 
where I can read the full docks?

Comment: Future vs blocking does not impact the protocol used to talk to the server.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand! :D